# how i can draw the custom border for my cardview?

Tags: android, layout, android-cardview

i used card view in my project,So i want to customize my card view.Actually i want to add a blue colour as card view border only.Please help to do this?
[image: this my actual design]

Comment: are you sure it's a cardview?

Comment: its jsut like design ,in my project i used recyclerview and cardview for displaying the items.So i want to chage the border color like this design